# self.port is undefined error [on mozilla add-on SDK 1.8]

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Following [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html) guide, I did a little variation and I keep receiving **this error**:

> self.port is undefined
>   at base.js[my content code]

here my **add-on code**:

```js
PageMod({
    include: [data.url('base.html')],
    contentScriptWhen: 'start',
    contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.7.2.min.js'),data.url('jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js'),data.url('base.js')],
    contentStyleFile: [data.url('css/mint-choc/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css'),data.url('css/base.css')],
    onAttach: function(worker) {
            worker.port.on("request", function(txt) {
                console.log(txt);
                worker.port.emit("response","response for "+txt);
            });
    }
});
```

and my **content code**:

```js
// initialized by jQuery
$(function() {
    self.port.on("response",function(txt){console.log("response "+txt);}) //this line is where the error point to.
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    testLoadLinks();
});

function testReceiveRequest(request) {
    console.log('received:',request);
    self.port.emit("request",request);
}
```

I'm using the browser editor with the SDK version 1.8, can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: It's not clear to my what is broken, and examples we have like this one ( https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1065275/latest/ ) work fine when using self.port in a content script.

Comment: @canuckistani I copied your code, and changed line 14 in main.js, you forgot the port in the worker.on, it worked as it should. But when I pull Firebug and type self.port.emit('from-content-script','test123') I still get the self.port is undefined error, is this function available for a limited time only? In my code we have jQuery calling that function only when the DOM is ready, maybe when the DOM is ready the self.port is already "gone" ?

Comment: 'self.port.on' only exists in the separate scope of the content script, and is definitely not defined in the main page scope. For more on content scripts, see the documentation: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html

Answer (score 1):

After some testing and debugging, I found out my two mistakes and i'm sorry i didn't put the whole code because I thought it wasn't related:

I had this in **base.html**

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/mint-choc/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/base.js"></script>
```

and this on **main.js**

```
PageMod({
include: [data.url("base.html")],
contentScriptWhen: 'start',
contentScriptFile: [data.url('jquery-1.7.2.min.js'),data.url('jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js'),data.url('base.js')],
contentStyleFile: [data.url('css/mint-choc/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css'),data.url('css/base.css')],
onAttach: function(worker) {
        console.log("attaching...")
        worker.port.on("request", function(txt) {
            console.log(txt);
            worker.port.emit("response","response for "+txt);
        });
}
});
```

My scripts are on the /data/js/ folder, they couldn't be found thus not loading the pageMod part of script in the main.js, but they were being loaded by the content script itself inside the DOM, where self.port is undefined. I just removed the script and styles tags from the base.html because they are already in the pageMod, and fixed the path in the data.url('js/base.js') and the others. Now i learned the scripts in the add-on scope can access the DOM scope and change it, but scripts inside the DOM cannot (they can?) communicate with the add-on scope. If you want scripts to interact with the add-on, you should left them in the add-on scope. I hope to help someone who commits the same mistake.
Thanks canuckistani.

Comment: Hi! Can you help me with the similar problem?

Comment: @user2543953, If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.