# Firefox sdk - content script can't access self.port

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to make a firefox addon using their sdk, but I don't know how to make my js scripts comunicate. The goal is to make a panel with a form in witch there are 3 checkboxes that when selected can hide/show certain elements on the active tab.

Here are the scripts: main.js:

```
exports.main = function() {};

var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var panel1 = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 215,
    height: 160,
    contentURL: data.url("panelDestroyer.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"),data.url("panel.js")]
});

require("sdk/widget").Widget({
    id: "open-form-btn",
    label: "Clear",
    contentURL: data.url("mozico.png"),
    contentScriptFile: data.url("jquery.js"),
    panel: panel1
});

var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var tabWorkers = {};
tabs.on("ready", function(tab) {
    attachTabWorker(tab);
});
for each (var tab in tabs) {
    attachTabWorker(tab);
}

function attachTabWorker(tab) {
    // Attach and store
    var tabWorker = tabWorkers[tab.id] = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: [data.url("clear.js"),data.url("jquery.js")]
    });
    // Clean up
    tabWorker.on("detach", function() {
        if (getTabWorker(tab) === tabWorker) {
            delete tabWorkers[tab.id];
        }
    });
}

function getTabWorker(tab) {
    return tabWorkers[tab.id];
}

function getActiveTabWorker() {
    return getTabWorker(tabs.activeTab);
}


panel1.port.on("show-tag",function(tag){
    getActiveTabWorker().port.emit("show-tag", tag);
    console.log("worker emited");
});

panel1.port.on("clear-tag",function(tag){
    getActiveTabWorker().port.emit("clear-tag", tag);
    console.log("worker emited");
})
```

;

painel.js:

```
    $("#imgD").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        self.port.emit("clear-tag","img");
        console.log("panel emited");
    } else {
       self.port.emit("show-tag","img");
       console.log("panel emited");
    }
});
$("#aD").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        self.port.emit("clear-tag","a");
        console.log("panel emited");
    } else {
        self.port.emit("show-tag","a");
        console.log("panel emited");
    }
});
$("#iframeD").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       self.port.emit("clear-tag","iframe");
       console.log("panel emited");
    } else {
        self.port.emit("show-tag","iframe");
        console.log("panel emited");
    }
});
```

clear.js:

```
    function tagHide (tag, hide) {
    $(tag).each(function() {
        if (hide === false) {
            $(this).css({
                "visibility": "visible"
            });
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
            });
        }
    });
}

self.port.on('show-tag', function(tag) {
    tagHide(tag, false);
});
self.port.on('clear-tag', function(tag) {
    tagHide(tag, true);
});
```

Why do I keep getting that self.port is not defined in painel.js ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to attach a content script *when the add-on is loaded*.

```
let worker = require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("clear.js")
});
```

I *think* `activeTab` may not be ready yet when your add-on is just loaded, which is usually when Firefox is starting. Perhaps the DOM is not fully loaded yet or the SDK could not properly initialize all components for the content script.

The SDK documentation [states](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/modules/sdk/tabs.html#ready_5) that you should wait until the `ready` event before using content-related properties and methods. I assume attaching content scripts also falls in that category, so you probably need to rework that to something like:

```
let worker = null;
require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.on("ready", function(tab) {
    worker = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: data.url("clear.js")
    });
});
```

This is still insufficient though, as the user may switch tabs. When you register the `ready` listener on the *original* `activeTab`, you won't be listening to the newly activated tab and no content scripts will be attached to that tab. You'll need to:

- listen to the `ready` event of *all* tabs;
- make sure they *all* have your content script attached;
- select the appropriate worker depending on the *currently* active tab.

I quickly whipped up something which *should* do just that. You should be able to use `getActiveTabWorker()` in your `panel` port events to target the correct worker. It's still untested, so give it a try!

```
const tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

let tabWorkers = {};
tabs.on("ready", function(tab) {
    attachTabWorker(tab);
});
for each (let tab in tabs) {
    attachTabWorker(tab);
}

function attachTabWorker(tab) {
    // Attach and store
    let tabWorker = tabWorkers[tab.id] = tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: data.url("clear.js")
    });
    // Clean up
    tabWorker.on("detach", function() {
        if (getTabWorker(tab) === tabWorker) {
            delete tabWorkers[tab.id];
        }
    });
}

function getTabWorker(tab) {
    return tabWorkers[tab.id];
}

function getActiveTabWorker() {
    return getTabWorker(tabs.activeTab);
}
```

**EDIT:** I have no idea *how* `self.port` can be undefined, but I found some more errors you need to fix. Perhaps one of those is indirectly interfering with `self`?

- `main.js` is listening for `hide-tag`, whereas your panel emits `clear-tag`. Use `clear-tag`.
- You're emitting an object to the worker, whereas your worker expects just a string. Simply emit `tag` instead of `{tag:tag}`.
- You're not including jQuery in your tab worker. Add `data.url("jquery.js")` to `contentScriptFile` in `attachTabWorker`.

Comment: I still get : Time: 03/06/2013 12:15:25 Error: TypeError: self.port is undefined Source: /data/pa‌​inel.js Line: 3

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro I have no idea how that can happen. Try fixing the other errors from my edit and see if it still happens.

Comment: I edited the "main.js" script in the question, see if you can find any reason , cause it still doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro Is `painel.js` still up-to-date? The version in your question doesn't reference `self` in any way (it references the non-existent `panel`). On a side note, you still haven't included jQuery in the tab worker's list of content scripts.

Comment: Still the same , is there a possibility that my panelDestroyer.html file might have problems?

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro Unlikely, but we can't know for sure if we can't see the code.

Comment: I don't know what happened but it started working and I'm 100% sure I didn't do anything. Must have been some issue with firefox or something. Thanks man, I did change const's and let's to var's and made all the changes you said I should , also I renamed painel.js to panel.js, but it wasnt working still. I guess rebboting firefox is always a good idea.

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro That's just... odd. Perhaps a previous version of your add-on attached a content script which did not get properly cleaned up. That might explain why you kept getting those error messages, even though your latest version was correct. I usually test my addons with `cfx run` so I start from a clean slate, and only sometimes I build an .xpi and try it out in my main Firefox install.

Answer (score 1):

I was also experiencing the same problem, and then found this question on SO: [self.port is undefined error [on mozilla add-on SDK 1.8]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426406/self-port-is-undefined-error-on-mozilla-add-on-sdk-1-8)

The problem is in the HTML code, you must be calling the script in both the main.js and html. Removing it from the html, and declaring it directly in main.js will solve this error.